# Computing multiple dot products of same dimension at same time

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix-multiplication

If we compute one dot product between a 4-element vector and a 4x4-matrix, we do

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.random.rand(4)

y = np.random.rand(4,4)

print(x.dot(y))
```

But what if I want to do the same thing, but for 10 different vectors and matrices at the same time (but with the same dimension)? I tried:

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.random.rand(10,4)

y = np.random.rand(10,4,4)

print(x.dot(y))
```

But it did not work. I also tried other methods but I could never get the desired output dimension `(10,4)`. What is the best way to do this without using a for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to work:

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.random.rand(10,4)

y = np.random.rand(10,4,4)

np.einsum("ij,ijk->ik", x, y)
```

Comment: `dot` made an 'outer' product on the lead dimensions, like an `einsum` with 'ij,kjl->ikl'.  You want its diagonal.  `matmul/@` can also do this by adding a size 1 dimension to `x`, 'i1j,ijk->i1k', where `i` is the "batch" dimension.

Answer (score 1):

You could use matrix-matrix multiplication.

The `@` operator broadcasts over everything but the last two dimensions. We can use this behaviour by temporarily inserting an extra dimension. This transforms x into a stack of 10 1x4 matrices. As the result of the matrix multiplication has the same shape as last step we remove the middle dimension.

```
>>> np.allclose((x[:, None] @ y)[:, 0], np.einsum("ij,ijk->ik", x, y))
# True
```

This method is more or less equivalent to the `einsum` method but marginally faster on my machine:

```
>>> timeit(lambda:np.einsum("ij,ijk->ik", x, y))
3.4603776139992988
>>> timeit(lambda:(x[:,None]@y)[:,0])
2.62706138700014
```